# How to Perform Innerjoin in access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

In Access I have a table like this:

```
data(BillNo number,acno number)
agro(BillNo number,Price number,qty number)
account(acno,Name)
```

I want an output like:

```
account.acno,account.Name,sum(agro.Price*agro.qty)
```

My query is:

```
SELECT account.accountnumber, 
       account.name, 
       Sum(agro.price * agro.qty) 
FROM   account 
INNER JOIN (agro 
            INNER JOIN data 
            ON agro.billno = data.billno) 
ON account.accountnumber = data.acno;
```

But it does not work. Please help me.

Comment: Thanks to all finally I get it:: Qyery is ----SELECT account.AccountNumber, account.Name, Sum(agro.price*agro.qty) AS Expr1
FROM account INNER JOIN (agro INNER JOIN data ON agro.BillNo = data.BillNo) ON account.AccountNumber = data.acno
GROUP BY account.AccountNumber, account.Name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up the text in your query.  Should be something like:

```
SELECT account.acno, account.Name,Sum(agro.Price*agro.qty)
FROM account 
INNER JOIN data ON account.acno= data.acno;
INNER JOIN agro On data .BillNo = agro.BillNo 
GROUP BY account.acno, account.name
```

Comment: Its Not work 'You Try to execute query that does not include the spececific expression 'Name' as part of an aggregate function' return this error

Comment: Oh, `GROUP BY account.acno, account.name`.

Comment: Its not work. Its raise an error please rewrite new query. Updated

Comment: @HirenRaiyani It's because `account.accountnumber` does not exist.  See the updated answer's query and let me know if that works.

Comment: @HirenRaiyani Glad to hear it.  Don't forget to mark this as your answer in that case.  :)

Comment: @James +1 Great mind think alike. and I'll delete my answer in a minute.